# Как поменять значения в столбце "name" на значения из столбца "category" при помощи функции?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм в котором хранятся данные о точках общественного питания. Для некоторых ресторанов под названием "кафе" не совпадает категория этого самого ресторана.

Если название ресторана "кафе" а категория "бар,паб" то название следует заменить на "бар,паб" и аналогично для всех значений по списку (все значения в столбце "name" == "кафе")

Всего уникальных значений категорий общественного питания 8:

1. кафе
2. ресторан
3. кофейня
4. бар.паб
5. пиццерия
6. быстрое питание
7. столовая
8. булочная

[image: Датафрейм, первая колонка "название ресторанов", вторая, их "категории"]

Хочу обернуть в собственную функцию данную процедуру, но не могу сообразить как это сделать.

```
def change_name(value):
   name = value['category']
   if name !=
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1** - выбрать все строки с "Кафе" `df.name.eq('Кафе')`, где имя не равно категории `~df.name.eq(df.category)`, и имена приравнять категориям:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Кафе'] * 6, 'category': ['Кафе', 'бар,паб'] * 3})
df.loc[mask, 'name'] = df.loc[(mask := df.name.eq('Кафе') & ~df.name.eq(df.category)), 'category']
print(df)
```

**Вариант 2** - учитывая, что название категории всегда первично, можно упростить выражение, удалив второе условие. В этом случае все "Кафе" в колонке `name` будут заменены на соответствующие названия из колонки `category`:

```
df.loc[mask, 'name'] = df.loc[(mask := df.name.eq('Кафе')), 'category']
```

```
      name category
0     Кафе     Кафе
1  бар,паб  бар,паб
2     Кафе     Кафе
3  бар,паб  бар,паб
4     Кафе     Кафе
5  бар,паб  бар,паб
```

Функцию, на мой взгляд, для этого делать нецелесообразно, поскольку ее применение замедлит выполнение.